# How can I edit text to look like the on on picture?

Tags: html, css

I am in school for web designer and we did course of html that's all good now in css that we are done. We got homework to do, we have to code 2 pages of our website that we are working on [page Contact us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kburT.jpg) and [About us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdYt.jpg), I have done page contact us. Now I need to do page about us and  I can't do the text over the images because I don't know how I tried something with in box and stuff like that but it didn't work, now here is my page of that site so as you can see we are using different classes for boxes and for division to get them in the same row so answers should be something like our code as it doesn't fit in our code and I get something completely different. [Text over the picture should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTdCR.jpg) We have to make that in css and html. We can't make picture in ps and put text over the image.

```css
/* CSS */

/* RESET ************************************************************************************************** */
*{box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;}

/* PRAVILA ZA OSNOVNO UREĐIVANJA HTML ELEMENATA *************************************************************** */
body{background-color:#b1b1b1;
color:white;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h5,.text{font-family: 'Racing Sans One', cursive;
font-weight:lighter;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,dl,li,dt,dd{margin-bottom:1em;}

ul{list-style-type:none; /* disc */}

a{text-decoration:none;
color:#2d2d2e;}

a:hover{color:orange !important;}

img,video{max-width:100%;
height:auto;}

a img:hover{opacity:0.5;}

/* HELPERS **************** */
.align-left{text-align:left;}
.align-right{text-align:right;}
.align-center{text-align:center;}
.align-justify{text-align:justify;}

/* LAYOUT ********************************************************************************************************* */
#page-footer, #content, #menu, #banner{padding:1rem;}
#page-header, #page-footer{background-color:#acacac;
color:white;}


.wrapper{max-width:1200px;
margin:0 auto;
/* border:4px dashed red; */}

.col{float:left;
margin-right:2%;}
.col:last-child{margin-right:0;}

.col-3{width:23.5%}
.col-4{width:32%;}
.col-6{width:49%;}
.col-8{width:66%;}

.clearfix:after{content:"";
clear:both;
display:block;}

.row{margin-bottom:1rem;}
.row:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}

/* MENU ********************************************************************************************************** */
/* IZBORNIK */
#menu li{display:inline;
margin-right:2rem;}

#menu a{ /* font-weight:bold; */
font-size:1.5rem; /* 24 / 16 =1.5rem */
color:white;}

#menu ul{margin-bottom:0;}
/* TRAŽILICA */

#search-icon{width:1.5rem;
vertical-align:middle;}

#s{width:90%;
padding:3px;}

/* BANNER ***************************************************************************************************** */
#banner{background:url(slike/header.jpg)center bottom/cover no-repeat;
height:40vh;  /* 440px / 1080px *100 =40.7% == 40.7vh */}

#banner h1{font-size:6rem; /* 96px / 16px =6rem*/}

/* #PAGE-FOOTER **************************************************************************************************************************** */
#page-footer a{margin:0 1rem;}

/* O NAMA ************************************************************************************** */
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3rem 1rem;
  /* fine tune this to adjust the box's dimensions */
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/* KONTAKT ************************************************** */
.font{font-size:1rem;
margin-right:2rem;}

#btn{padding:4px 9rem;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Ziga">
    <title>O nama-Avanturust</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Racing+Sans+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="page-header">
        <nav id="menu">
            <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="col col-8">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.htm">Naslovnica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="onama.htm">O nama</a></li>
                        <li><a href="kontakt.htm">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- .col end -->
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <form action="" name="search-form" id="search-form">
                        <input type="text" name="s" id="s">
                        <input type="image" src="slike/search.png" alt="search" id="search-icon">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- .col end -->
            </div>
            <!-- .wrapper end -->
        </nav>
        <!-- #menu end -->
        
        <div id="banner"> 
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>AVANTURIST</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- .wrapper end -->
        </div>
        <!-- #banner end -->
    </header>
    <!-- #page-header end -->
    
    <main id="content">
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <section id="primary" class="col col-8">
                <h2>O nama</h2>
                <h3>Naš stručni team</h3>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="col col-3">
                        <p class="text">Maja Majić</p>
                        <img src="slike/lica/maja.svg" alt="Maja Majić">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col -->
                    <div class="col col-3">
                        <p class="text">Pero Perić</p>
                        <img src="slike/lica/pero.svg" alt="Pero">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col -->
                    <div class="col col-3">
                        <p class="text">Mirko i Slavko</p>
                        <img src="slike/lica/mirko.svg" alt="Mirko">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col -->
                    <div class="col col-3">
                        <p class="text">Ivan Ivanović</p>
                        <img src="slike/lica/ivan.svg" alt="Ivan">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col -->
                </div>
                
            </section>
            <!-- #primary end -->           
            <aside id="sidebar" class="col col-4">
                <h2>Last minute</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h2>Ponuda mjeseca</h2>
                <video src="video/promo.mp4" controls></video>
            </aside>
            <!-- #sidebar end -->
        </div>
        <!-- .wrapper end -->
    </main>
    <!-- #content end -->
    
    <footer id="page-footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>AVANTURIST</h1>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                </div>
                <!-- .col end -->
                <div class="col col-4 align-center">
                    <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="slike/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="slike/instagram.png" alt="insagram">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src="slike/twitter.png" alt="twitter">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- .col end -->
                <div class="col col-4  align-right">
                    <p>AVANTURIST &copy; 2020. </p>
                </div>
                <!-- .col end -->
            </div>
            <!-- .row end -->
            
        </div>
        <!-- .wrapper end -->
    </footer>
    <!-- #page-footer end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, It would be great if you could share your code to let everyone know as to what you've done, what all you've already tried and where you are currently stuck.

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question as we are unable to debug images.

Comment: I did, sry for my mistake in posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could accomplish it using [**CSS pseudo-elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

```css
/* applies to the outer box */

.container {
  /* flex-direction defaults to row (places elements inside side by side) */
  display: flex;
}


/* applies to the inner boxes that contain the spans with texts */

.box {
  /* this regulates the distance between the boxes in this case */
  margin: 0px 20px;
}


/*
CSS pseudo-elements
generate block elements both before and after the CONTENT of the box (the span)
*/

.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "|";
  /* you must ALWAYS provide a textual content to pseudo-elements */
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  background-color: #555;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: impact;
  padding: 3px 16px;
  /* fine tune this to adjust the box's dimensions */
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"><span class="text">text 1</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span class="text">text 2</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span class="text">text 3</span></div>
    <div class="box"><span class="text">text 4</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used your text class but the other thing dosen't fit in our code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a font, search for the font you want in google and add it like this:

```
font-family: YOUR FONT
```

Comment: Thanks, but i mean for image or what ever is behind the text becuase i already set font-family, not i don't know is this picture or something in text-decoration

Comment: if it was me I will just do it with photoshop and place the text on top

Comment: I would too, i already thinked about it but my professor said it needs to be done in html or css and i don't know how haha. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar font would be something like Impact. Use that font, or any other using the "font-family" property.

Additionally, to position text over an image, do something like this

```
<img src="crabnebula.jpg" alt="crabnebula" style = "width:10%;height:10%;">
<p style = "position: absolute;top:5%;left: 5%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);color:white;">Ok</p>
```

Comment: We need to make this in css and html i can't use photo and put text on it i asked already :) . Thanks.